# Outlook 2011: Re-mapping keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: macos, ms-office

At work I'm using Outlook 2011 and OSX 10.10. I just sent yet another incomplete email accidentally with the shortcut CMD + right enter. Is there any way to disable this shortcut? Googling around shows adding keyboard shortcuts into OSX itself but not Outlook. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't disable it, but you can re-map the shortcut so you're far less likely to hit it.

Open System Preferences, go to Keyboard > Shortcuts (tab)> App Shortcuts (Left field). Click the "+", select "Microsoft Outlook" from the "Application:" list, change "Menu Title:" to "Send," and change the shortcut to something you aren't likely to hit accidentally, such as Shift + CMD + Option + G," or similar.

[image]

Close and re-open Outlook. Enjoy not accidentally sending unfinished eMail!

Comment: I tried the solution above and it didn't disable cmd+enter it just added an additional short cut. this is awful! any help??

Comment: It does work, you just have to close and re-open Outlook. I'm using 14.5.8 on El Capitan (10.11.3). Thanks Rampant for the fix!

Comment: @BenCourliss - I'm trying this for disabling Select All (Outlook 16.16 on Sierra (10.12.6)), and I'm having the same issue as user above, even with completely restarting - it adds a shortcut, but doesn't disable the old one